# How to factorise a cubic?

Tags: factoring, cubics

What are the steps in factorising a cubic?

For example $x^{3} - 2x^{2} - 7x - 4$

I know that $-1$ is a root so it will start off as $(x+1)$(...something?)

Comment: And what is *something* in your opinion ?

Comment: If you know one of the roots of the cubic equation, you can perform what is called synthetic division to find other factors. This might be useful: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/synthdiv.htm

Comment: You perform polynomial division to find the (...something?) in your question.  It will be a quadratic.  So then you have to factor a quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know $-1$ is a root you can use [Ruffini's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule):

[image]

Then $x^3-2x^2-7x-4=(x+1)(x^2-3x-4)$

And you can easily see that $-1$ and $4$ are roots of $(x^2-3x-4)$

Then $x^3-2x^2-7x-4=(x+1)(x^2-3x-4)=(x+1)(x+1)(x-4)$

**Note:** Before using Ruffini's rule you can also see that $4$ is a root using [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, then $\, f = (x\!+\!1)(x^2\!+bx-4)$  $\,\overset{\large x\,=\,1}\Longrightarrow\,-12 = f(1) = 2(b-3)\,\Rightarrow\, b = -3$

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know that $x+1$ is a factor, try to extract it i.e

$$x^{3} - 2x^{2} - 7x - 4 = (x^3+x^2) -(3x^2+3x) -(4x+4) $$
$$(x^3+x^2) -(3x^2+3x) -(4x+4) = (x+1)(x^2-3x-4)=(x+1)(x+1)(x-4)$$

Hence you have $$x^{3} - 2x^{2} - 7x - 4= (x+1)(x+1)(x-4) $$

Answer (score 0):

I think a numerical approach is possible. By The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, we know $x^3−2x^2−7x−4=0=(x+1)(ax^2+bx+c)$. So lets, consider $g(x)=\frac{x^3-2x^2-7x-4}{x+1}$

and let 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)}$$

Start with $x_0=0$ and iterate until $|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ is stable or within some predetermined small value, $\epsilon>0$.

A stable $x_n$ should be a root, call it $r_1$.

then instead of $g(x)$, use $h(x)=g(x)/(x-r_1)$ and iterate. This should give you the second root.

Things need to be adjusted if there are not 3 real roots.